# Display Time Elapsed Since Start of Game in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

My goal is to display the time elapsed since the start of the game (this should be updated continuously).

I know how to find the time elapsed from the start until the end of the game. But I cannot figure out how to continuously update on the screen with the stopwatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

starting a timer with

self.updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(*whatever you've called the method where you update the display to show current time*) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

will update your display ever second

Comment: True. And you can use a UILabel to display the time. Just change the label text to the new time and call setNeedsDisplay. Do that within the @selector(updateTimeDisplay:)...